# Termux - npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, node-modules, termux

I get these errors when running npm install on Termux (Android). Any solution?

I get these errors when running npm install on Termux (Android). Any solution?

```
$ npm install
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.8 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.8: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"android","arch":"arm64"})

npm ERR! path ../@babel/parser/bin/babel-parser.js
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! errno -1
npm ERR! syscall symlink
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, symlink '../@babel/parser/bin/babel-parser.js' -> '/storage/emulated/0/web/tbcians/node_modules/.bin/parser'
npm ERR!  { [OperationalError: EPERM: operation not permitted, symlink '../@babel/parser/bin/babel-parser.js' -> '/storage/emulated/0/web/tbcians/node_modules/.bin/parser']
npm ERR!   cause:
npm ERR!    { [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, symlink '../@babel/parser/bin/babel-parser.js' -> '/storage/emulated/0/web/tbcians/node_modules/.bin/parser']
npm ERR!      errno: -1,
npm ERR!      code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!      syscall: 'symlink',
npm ERR!      path: '../@babel/parser/bin/babel-parser.js',
npm ERR!      dest: '/storage/emulated/0/web/tbcians/node_modules/.bin/parser' },
npm ERR!   stack:
npm ERR!    "Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, symlink '../@babel/parser/bin/babel-parser.js' -> '/storage/emulated/0/web/tbcians/node_modules/.bin/parser'",
npm ERR!   errno: -1,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'symlink',
npm ERR!   path: '../@babel/parser/bin/babel-parser.js',
npm ERR!   dest: '/storage/emulated/0/web/tbcians/node_modules/.bin/parser' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator (though this is not recommended).

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /data/data/com.termux/files/home/.npm/_logs/2019-04-21T09_30_40_780Z-debug.log
$
```

Comment: Have you tried with sudo npm install?

Comment: Can't use sudo on Termux. My device is not rooted.

Comment: You can check this link https://github.com/st42/termux-sudo, to add termux sudo privileges

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Android does not allow symlinks to exist in the Internal Shared storage, simply moving the directory `web` from your Internal Storage to the Termux home directory which lies in the data partition, will solve your error. In order to do this, simply use the command `mv -r /sdcard/web ~`. Note that this will move your directory named `web` to `/data/data/com.termux/files/home/web`.

Answer (score 0):

or you can just move your entire project to termux home directory

Answer (score -1):

Here's a simple way to fix this:

1. Go to settings
2. Go to app management
3. App settings
4. Select Termux
5. Go to permission
6. Than click allow file and Media

DONE

Comment: Allowing the app to have the permission to use the files doesn't allow symlinks at all. Unless you have root access, you have to move the project to termux's directory, at least up till today.